# Trouble with setlocale

Tags: php, localization, gettext

Does anyone happen to know why a call to `setlocale` would fail for a reason other than the locale package not existing. The following code:

```
$language = 'fr_CA.utf8';
//putenv("LANG=" . $language); 

var_dump(setlocale(LC_ALL, $language));

// Set the text domain as "messages"
$domain = "messages";
$result = bindtextdomain($domain, ROOT_DIR . "../locale/");

bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');

$result = textdomain($domain);

echo _("IAMSOMETEXT");
echo $result;die;
```

outputs `bool(false)` from the `var_dump`. We are running the site in **Vagrant**, however I ran `locale -a` on the **VM**, and *fr_CA.utf8* was indeed in the output. I have tried other variations that were listed such as simply *fr_CA*.

Setting the locale to *en_US.utf8* works perfectly however. *POSIX* does seem to work as well.  Has anyone ran into this issue? We are running **Ubuntu 12.04** on the **VM**.

Comment: `fa_CA.utf8` doesn't work for me either. `fra_can` works. `fra_can.utf8` doesn't. Two letter language codes don't seem to work for me: `en_us` vs `eng_usa`.

Comment: are those available in your locale -a outputs?

Comment: If you type "LC_ENV=fr_CA.utf8 date" on the command line, is the date printed in French? How about "echo exec('locale -a');" in PHP? Is it a plain Ubuntu 12.04 installation?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Session.LCID`, which should have read/write access.  It's a number, like 1034